# How to convert 3 duplicated conditional rules 2007 to VBA code 2003?

Tags: vba, excel

I have got a file working in Excel 2007 but I need to convert for Excel 2003.

```
Rule 1 : Formula (F13 is true), Range (from A10 to A30), fill background in Red
Rule 2 : Formula (F13 is true), Range (from B10 to B30), fill background in Red
Rule 3 : Formula (F13 is true), Range (from C10 to C30), fill background in Red
```

I want to have a VBA code to do that (I also want to prevent to repeat 3 times the same code).

Thanks!

Comment: What *exactly* is stopping you from achieving this yourself?  Do you have a specific problem?  If you include your own try in the question you're much more likely to get help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically you want VBA code to mimic Excel 2007+ conditional formatting in prior versions. If that's the case then I am pretty sure you'll have to go with the Worksheet_Change event in order to capture any changes to the sheet. Then you can test if the changes fulfill your criteria requirements and implement the desired action:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = False
    .EnableEvents = False
End With

If Not Intersect(Target, Range("F13")) Is Nothing Then
    Range("A10:A30").Interior.Color = vbRed
End If

With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = True
    .EnableEvents = True
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Ralph, thanks for your reply. I am going to test this code and I will tell you if it's working. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I just had to change to : If Range("F13").Value = True Then. Now it works perfect, thanks a lot !